# I was sorry to call you/have called you/be calling you

Tags: infinitives

If I say "I am sorry to have called you last week" it will mean that I regret calling you last week.

If I say "I was sorry to call you last week", what will it mean?

> a) Before calling you last week I felt sorry but I called anyway
>
> b) I called you last week and then after I called I felt sorry

If I am talking to someone on the phone and I want to apologize for calling, will these two work?

> c) I am sorry to be calling you.
>
> d) I am sorry to have called you.

Comment: "I'm sorry to bother/trouble you" would be more natural (apologising for disturbing them and/or taking up their time).

Comment: Option (c) is outright horrible.  An apology must express regret, a change in attitude.  But in (c) there cannot be a change; the conflicting attitudes "I *am* calling" and "I *am* sorry" are both in the present. The fact that you're still doing the offensive action proves you aren't sorry, and a hollow apology is worse than no apology at all. (Consider: it is not necessary for a long time to have passed, the regret can be brought by learning information. *When I called, I didn't realize you were sleeping. Now only 10 seconds later the new information put me into a position of being sorry.*)

Answer (score 4):

The second sentence in the first question is a little strange because "I was sorry" is past tense. So, you were sorry in the past. It could mean either a) or b), because both put the feeling (being sorry) in the past.

As to apologizing in the present (second question), c) is more understandable because of simple present tense: I *am* sorry (for calling right now). The phrasing in d) is what you might use to apologize in the present for a previous call: *I am sorry for having called you last week. I was in a bad mood and I know I was rude during the call.*

Answer (score 1):

Do not use either of these!

“I am sorry to be calling you” implies you do not enjoy talking to him!

“I am sorry to have called you” is grammatically wrong, since the call is not complete *and* implies you do not enjoy talking to him.

Say “Sorry to disturb you.”